# German equivalent to "out of scope"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I am currently translating an English specification for a software that needs to be implemented. In this specification, a few features that could be thought as "natural enhancements" need to be explicitly ruled out because there is not enough time to implement them.

The document uses the term "out of scope" to describe the core of the rejection for these aspects in an accurate manner: Although these features would feel like "natural additions", the defined scope of the project is very narrow and will not be broadened.

What would be a German equivalent to capture the gist for this kind of rejection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have some doubts, whether *out of scope* can be well translated without additional context.

In your specific context I propose something like:

> künftigen Erweiterungen/Versionen vorbehalten

Comment: I agree. Translating "out of scope" without providing any additional context is not possible.

Comment: In this specific context, I chose this as an accepted answer because it exactly expresses what I mean, even tough it's not a direct translation.

Comment: This answer is super wrong. In any case even with context information. "Out of scope" can never be translated into "future changes under reserve".

Answer (score 32):

My proposal:

> nicht im Rahmen (des Projektes) / nicht im (vorgesehenen) Zielrahmen (Anwendungsrahmen)

Usage example:

> Der Verbesserungsvorschlag musste leider abgelehnt werden, da er nicht in den vorgesehenen Anwendungsrahmen passt.

Comment: Ich würde noch "sprengt den Rahmen" erwähnen!

Comment: "Sprengt den Rahmen" gefällt mir sehr gut, ist in einem formalen Kontext aber wohl leider nicht angebracht :(

Comment: @MarcusRiemer Wenn *sprengt den Rahmen* nicht passt (weil es nicht formell genug ist), kann man das Ganze offizieller ausdrücken: *Der Verbesserungsvorschlag muss abgelehnt werden, da er mit den terminlichen bzw. budgetären Rahmenbedingungen des Projekts nicht konform ist.* oder *Der Verbesserungsvorschlag muss abgelehnt werden, da der Aufwand für dessen Umsetzung ausserhalb der terminlichen und budgetären Einschränkungen des Projekts liegt.* Ich will aber betonen, dass formeller nicht unbedingt besser ist.

Comment: @MarcusRiemer Ich dachte "out of scope" sei auch informell (für "beyond the scope") und sogar weniger für diesen Kontext geeignet, aber ich will mich im Englischen nicht zu weit vorwagen...

Comment: That should be _vorgesehenen_, shouldn't it?

Comment: "out of scope" would be used in a formal context by a US Project Manager, both in written (documentation) and spoken (conference address) communication. A native local practitioner in the field (myself included) would not hear/read this as wrong or informal.

Comment: @Ludi Not saying that it 'wasn't' or 'shouldn't' be informal, just its usage now 'isn't' informal.

Answer (score 9):

"Scope" one can translate with "Geltungsbereich", "Spielraum" oder "Leistungsumfang, -bereich".

"Außerhalb des Leistungs[-bereichs or -umfangs]" or respectively "Nicht innerhalb des Leistungs[-bereichs or -umfangs]" should be a good translation.

Perhaps it helps you to have an additional view on this: http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=out+of+scope

Answer (score 2):

In your context,

> Nicht (Bestand)teil dieses Angebots.

might do. In a less formal environment one could also say

> zu viel des Guten

Answer (score 1):

> Am Anwendungsbereich vorbeigehen/An der Anwendung vorbeigehen

These translations mean the same too:

> Feature sprengt den Rahmen des Anwendungsbereichs  .. der Software
>
> Feature deckt sich nicht mit dem Anwendungsbereich .. der Software
>
> Feature liegt außerhalb des Anwendungsbereichs .. der Software
>
> Feature ist nicht anwendungsbezogen

Comment: Was für ein Paper?

Comment: Was not carefully reading the question, thought a paper got rejected :D updated

Comment: Even after the edit this answer seems not really to match the question. As I understand the author wants to translate the specification himself and looks for a way to tag some quite reasonable features as "not addressed (yet)" to justify a limited effort. Since these were already confirmed as "natural extensions" all examples of missing *Themenbereich* are at least debatable .

Comment: good point, i changed